# Find the closure and interior of intervals [a,b],(a,b) $\subset$ R in \Tau_{R}^{c} if a< b?

Tags: general-topology

Given that $\tau_{X}^{c} = \{S ⊂ X:X \setminus S \text{ is finite or countable}\}  \bigcup \emptyset \subset P(X)$

I have tried to answer it using a similar question:

For the interval [a,b]

The interior Int {[a,b] $\subset$ R} is the largest open set contained in {[a,b] $\subset$ R}.The fact that it is open in Tau_R implies it can only be equal to either **the empty set** (1) or **the complementary of a finite set** (2). The fact Int{[a,b] $\subset$ R}⊂ {[a,b] $\subset$ R}
implies R\ {[a,b] ⊂ R} ⊂ R\ Int{[a,b] $\subset$ R}, hence the fact R\ {[a,b] $\subset$ R} is not finite implies that the set containing it, R\ Int{[a,b] $\subset$ R} is infinite as well which leaves us with  1:
Int{[a,b] $\subset$ R}= empty set

The closure clos{[a,b] $\subset$ R} is the smallest closed set containing {[a,b] $\subset$ R}.  The fact that it is closed, by definition, leaves only two options: either **Clos{[a,b] $\subset$ R}= R**
(1) or **Clos{[a,b] $\subset$ R} is finite** (2). Again, {[a,b] $\subset$ R} is an infinite set and
the fact that {[a,b] $\subset$ R} $\subset$ Clos{[a,b] $\subset$ R} implies {[a,b] $\subset$ R} is an infinite set as well, hence discarding 2:
Clos{[a,b] $\subset$ R} = R

For the interval(a,b), following the same working as above, would it yield the same answer as [a,b]? 
Is my working correct?

Comment: As a short terminology note, the term "countable" usually means "finite or countably infinite", therefore you can shorten the definition of your topology to remove the word "finite"  (And indeed, this is usually called the countable complement topology)

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the interior being empty for all these intervals. There can be no set with only countable complement inside them, as the complement of any subset of the interval at least contains the complement of said interval, which is never at most countable.

The only closed sets are finite sets, countable sets and $X$. No member of the first two can contain any interval so the onle closed set around an open interval is $X$. So there you were right as well.